# Flutter MaterialApp conditional builder

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-getx

I am using the builder function of my MaterialApp to wrap my routes with a widget.
But I only want to show the wrapper on specific routes.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Actually I am using GetX and GetMaterialApp, but I don't think that it makes any difference.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GetMaterialApp(
       home: HomeScreen(),

       builder: (context, child) {
          //Only show GlobalPlayerWrapper on specific routes
         return GlobalPlayerWrapper(child: child!);
       },

       title: 'Aschaffenburg',
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You coul use MaterialApp's onGenerateRoute callback to generate different results depending on the route:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
              case'/':
                 return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen());
              case '/otherPage':
                 /* return other page route with your wrapper*/
          }
      },
      initialRoute: MateriealPageRoute(builder:(_) => HomeScreen()),
);
```